# Create new item in modern experience

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list that explicitly uses the modern experience.[image: screenshot of list experience setting]

The create and edit view are also set to open in a dialog.
[image: screenshot of dialog setting]

Even so, whenever I create a new list item, it opens in its own page in the classic experience. This poses a problem, as one of the required fields is a location column, and when I to fill that field and submit, I get a validation error about an `Invalid JSON primitive`.

Weirdly enough, the create view worked just fine through the sidebar dialog last week and I did not change anything other than a column formatting since then.

For completion's sake, this is the column formatting

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "@currentField"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "=if(@currentField != '', 'm²', '')",
            "style": {
                "padding": "0 1px"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way I can force Sharepoint to use the dialog again? Or at least properly add my location field through the classic view?

Answer (score 0):

For keeping to open with classic issue, what the column formatting you added before you found the issue?

As a workaround, you can save the list as template (include content) and create a new list to use this saved template, check if you can create new item with new experience.

For the location column issue, since location column is a new experience feature, we can only select location in the new experience. In the classic experience, I open an exiting value in location column in my environment and find the column format as below:

```
{"LocationSource":"Bing","LocationUri":"https://www.bingapis.com/api/v6/localentities/41c08f01-65b9-ccd4-1340-2d416e267849?setLang=en","UniqueId":"https://www.bingapis.com/api/v6/localentities/41c08f01-65b9-ccd4-1340-2d416e267849?setLang=en","DisplayName":"Chinatown, Singapore, Singapore","Address":{"City":"Singapore","CountryOrRegion":"Singapore","Street":"Chinatown, Singapore, Singapore"},"Coordinates":{"Latitude":1.2847900390625,"Longitude":103.84419250488281}}
```

Comment: The column formatting just adds a span with "m²" to a column, to properly indicate square meters. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: My users are very much not technical, so expecting them to add JSON content when they create an item will not work, I'm afraid.

I tried out your suggestion with creating a new list from the old one, but sadly the behavior persists.